# What is the use case for `dplyr::select`?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I generally really like the whole [`tidyverse`](http://tidyverse.org/) paradigm and use it extensively.

But I simply do not understand `select` in `dplyr`.  How is it ever more useful than simply selecting the columns via

```
my_df[,cols_of_interest]
```

?

The "vanilla" R method seems so much easier, as well as far more robust.  I can have `cols_of_interest` as a variable, as above, or I can put in literal names. Trying to use variables, then use `select_`, then try to wrangle with the whole manner in which `lazyeval` might interpret my intentions just seems crazy.

Is there a ***programmatic*** case where `select` is more advantageous over simply `my_df[,cols_of_interest]`?  (I very rarely write any code "once" these days, so anything that is not programmatic is not particularly useful.)

At the moment, I find myself very often doing things like:

```
new_df <- (old_df %>%
    filter_(paste0("`",col_name, "`=='",col_val,"'")))[cols_to_keep]
```

which is kinda ugly, but at least it works, unlike any attempts to perform

```
new_df <- old_df %>%
    filter_(paste0("`",col_name, "`=='",col_val,"'")) %>%
    select_(cols_to_keep)
```

which fails outright.

I can give an explicit example, but that kinda misses the point.  What is the use case for `select` **over** simply choosing `my_df[,cols_of_interest]`?

Comment: It's pipable, primarily. It also uses NSE (nice for interactive sessions), can be used to selectively rename, and has a nice set of helper functions like `num_range`. It also works transparently with dplyr's various backends (various SQL flavors, sparklyr, multidplyr). FYI, the `verb_` versions are being deprecated in the forthcoming version in favor of [rlang syntax](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/vignettes/programming.Rmd).

Comment: Here's what I like with select - using it to select sequentially a few variable names e.g.  `mtcars %>% select(mpg, wt, vs:carb) %>% names`. This will give a usable vector `"mpg"  "wt"   "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"`

Comment: The equivalent of `my_df[,cols_of_interest]` is `my_df %>% select(one_of(cols_of_interest))`

Comment: ...or `mtcars %>% select_(.dots = c('mpg', 'hp'))` with the current version or `mtcars %>% select(!!!rlang::syms(c('mpg', 'wt')))` with 0.6

Comment: Look at `?select_helpers` for greater select flexibility

Comment: A possible programmatic advantage is that `select` always returns a data.frame, which `df[ , ...]` doesn't if `df` is a vanilla data.frame and `...` is a single variable. Subsetting without the comma in base (e.g. `mtcars['wt']`) is actually safer, though maybe less intuitive at first.

Comment: I agree with you that the 'verbs' can get out of hand. I guess one benefit is the ability to rename a column while selecting it. Base would be harder. `select(mtcars, miles=mpg, am:carb)` and the colon operator for a range of rows is pretty cool.

Comment: @alistaire Yes, you've hit upon the crux of it.  I understand that's what is nice about `select`.  However, I find even more often that when I am selecting a single column, it's because I actually want it as a vector.  But you're correct, if I want a single column to remain as a dataframe, and not be coerced "without my permission", then `select` has a good use case.

Comment: The class consistency is really important for programmatic use when you don't actually know if the user will be selecting one column or multiple, but still need to do something with the result. Ultimately it's not that everything can't be done in base—it can; it just requires extra care.

Comment: It's more elegant

Comment: `select` is the NSE version that's good for interactive sessions, while `select_` is the 'programmatic' version. Many of `dplyr`'s functions have NSE and non-NSE variants. Check out `dplyr`'s NSE vignette.

Comment: It lets you avoid typing quote marks

Comment: Another difference in usability is that you would need to do `my_df[,cols_of_interest, drop=FALSE]` if you want to be sure that the result is a data frame as well. Otherwise for the case where you only have one "column of interest" the result will be just a vector. `dplyr::select` on the other hand never coerces to a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `select` for interactive sessions and `select_` for 'programmatic' purposes...

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>% select(Sepal.Width, Petal.Width)

cols_of_interest <- c("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Width")
iris %>% select_(.dots = cols_of_interest)
```

additional clarification...

also, notice that the following two line are **not** the same...

```
iris %>% select_("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Width")
iris %>% select_(c("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Width"))
```

which is why this does not work like you were expecting it to..

```
iris %>% select_(cols_of_interest)
```

`select_` can handle the strings, but if you're feeding it a vector with multiple strings, it doesn't know what to do with it (in this case it just takes the first element and ignores the rest). In the first example, you're passing two separate strings to two separate arguments, whereas in the second (and third) you're passing a two element vector to one argument.

Comment: Thanks, CJ.  Part of my struggle was that I'm normally in the programmatic mode, which does not fit well with much of `tidyverse`.  But part of my struggle was actually that I was using it wrong.  I did not understand how `.dots` should be used.

Comment: I added some clarification

Answer (score 0):

Independently I can't give a strong reason for using select, but in the context of the rest of dplyr and combined with magrittr it allows something like

```
x %>% filter(col1 == "foo")
    %>% select(col2, col3)
    %>% mutate(col4 = f(col2, col3))
```

which provides very nice consistent syntax though a series of manipulations.

Comment: Hi @shians Yes, I understand the basic use case.  But in the example you've given, it is not programmatic.  I.e., `col2` and `col3` have to be the ***actual names*** of the columns, and not string variables.  I rarely work in that world of "write once" anymore.  And, maybe I'm wrong, but I feel that fewer R users are also working in that "write once" interactive mode, too.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson That's a bad assumption; if questions here are any indicator, R is used much more interactively than programmatically. Code gets recycled, sure, but if the data format is standardized enough, that doesn't require a different approach to rerun an analysis on new data. Further, if you want, you can program directly with "actual names"—really language objects of various sorts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not exactly sure of the *use case* of `select` (or `select_`), barring the case where you want to keep a single column as a data frame type instead of being coerced into a vector.

However, to partially answer my own question I have at least figured out the `tidyverse`-friendly way of doing what I'd wanted to do, programmatically.

```
> mt_dt <- as_tibble(mtcars)
> expr1 <- quote(cyl == 8)
> cols_oi <- c("mpg", "cyl")
> mt_dt %>% filter_(.dots=expr1) %>% select_(.dots=cols_oi)

(This returns only the mpg & cyl columns, only when the cyl == 8.)
```

So it seems that **we use `.dots` in any situation where you might want to effectively use `tidyverse` programmatically**. However, as the example above shows, its usage is not obvious: sometimes you should provide an unevaluated expression, like you get from `quote` or `substitute`, and sometimes a simple string, like you'd provide in any example where standard expressions are first-class.  While I could not find detailed documentation on `dots`, several re-reads of [this non-standard documentation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) helped a lot.